# Rails: Javascript not getting to heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My javascript is not making it to my heroku app even though my application.html.haml file has: 
`= javascript_include_tag "application"`. I threw in an alert to check if any js is making it there but no cigar. I also checked in firebug and the javascript isn't being sent to the browser what-so-ever. Any ideas?

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require autoNumeric
//= require lightbox

alert('test?');
```

Production.rb

```
MyMyApp::Application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true (I tried false)
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

**ruby '2.0.0'**

**gem 'rails', '3.2.13'**

Comment: Does your application.js have the alert code inside or not if you do View Source on Heroku?

Comment: if you want the alert to appear you have to add //= require_self

Comment: Not necessary the alert appears in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with asset pipeline and heroku. Check this linke

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Or simply put into config/application.rb line:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

This should solve your problems cheers.

Comment: can you post your javascript include tag from application layout ? and config/environments/production.rb files

Comment: I added the production.rb

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

-> Try to call when document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

-> Try to precompile assets before pushing to Heroku:

in your production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

in your cmd:

```
> rake assets:precompile
> git push heroku master
```

Comment: it is alert it will work anyway. I think the problem is that heroku is not serving his assets.